# How to make iOS app cache ALL request responses?

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, afnetworking

I'm starting to work on an app which will include in quite a few places data that I will download from my server each time user is asking to view them. Then, when user opens app again without any internet connection, app should let him view any content it previously downloaded, just loading it from the cache. The point of this is that the content changes from time to time and user needs to be able to see the last downloaded version if he can't connect to the server.

Problem is, I can set the cache to a certain size on disk, but I have to store ALL the content no matter the size. I suppose I'd have to set cache disk size to make it bigger when it's running out of space. What is a good way to do this?

P.S. Not sure if this is relevant, but I was thinking about trying AFNetworking for this project (previously I used ASIHTTPRequest).

Comment: Better save the downloaded content in the document directory when it is used first. For later use, bring it from the document directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `NSURLCache` as an on-disk cache, you can check the disk usage with `currentDiskUsage`. If this is approaching `diskCapacity`, you can increase it using `setDiskCapacity`. You should perform this check **before** you attempt to write to the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on same type of project, I used AFNetworking and according to me storing the data in local database is better option then caching it... and at the time when user starts app just have one service call which just checks the database version. If its old version replace database and handle the case if network fails by displaying the older version.